# Detect gaps over 30 min in timestamp column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have read up on and attempted using the standard method of gaps and island detection in a series with no success because I need to be able to ignore any gaps less than 30 minutes.  I can not use a cursor due to performance issues.

Everytime there is a gap of at least 30 min, I need a new row with the start and end. If there are no gaps of at least 30, result would be one row with the min and max of the timestamps.  If there is 1 gap of at least 30, there would be 2 rows - from the start of the series to the gap and from the gap to the end.  If there are more gaps, we get rows for each interval between the gaps, etc.

Input:

```
timestamp 

2015-07-15 15:01:21 
2015-07-15 15:17:44 
2015-07-15 15:17:53 
2015-07-15 15:18:34 
2015-07-15 15:21:41 
2015-07-15 15:58:12 
2015-07-15 15:59:12 
2015-07-15 16:05:12
2015-07-15 17:02:12
```

Desired output :

```
from | to

2015-07-15 15:01:21 | 2015-07-15 15:21:41 
2015-07-15 15:58:12 | 2015-07-15 16:05:12
2015-07-15 17:02:12 | 2015-07-15 17:02:12
```

Comment: You desired result is not match with what you have asked for. the difference between times in the first row, is 20 minutes not 30 minutes.

Comment: I have tried cursor which takes too long on my data set.  I have also tried the standard gaps and island method but could not figure out how to adapt it to IGNORE gaps less than 30 min

Comment: I don't understand your desired output at all. The first five records are all only some minutes apart. Only after 15:21:41  there is a big gap till 15:58:12 and the next big gap is after 16:05:12 till 17:02:12.

Comment: Think about cursors when tasks like this will become easy game. Cursors are the last defense when you you can do nothing more. May I also add that your data have nothing to `timestamp` datatype.

Comment: A series is defined by a run of multiple rows where the time between *consecutive* timestamps is never more than 30 minutes. The output is the earliest and latest times across each such series.

Answer (score 5):

Easy solution using common table expression. Compare with cursor performance if you have at least 1000 rows.

```
create table #tmp (Dt datetime)

insert into #tmp values 
('2015-07-15 15:01:21'),
('2015-07-15 15:17:44'), 
('2015-07-15 15:17:53'), 
('2015-07-15 15:18:34'), 
('2015-07-15 15:21:41'), 
('2015-07-15 15:58:12'), 
('2015-07-15 15:59:12'), 
('2015-07-15 16:05:12'),
('2015-07-15 17:02:12')

;with tbl as (
select dt, row_number() over(order by dt) rn
from #tmp
)
select t1.dt [from],t2.dt [to], datediff(minute,t1.dt,t2.dt) gap
from tbl t1 
inner join tbl t2 on t1.rn+1 = t2.rn
where datediff(minute,t1.dt,t2.dt) >30
```

Comment: Accept if you like.

Comment: Need some time to review and test.  Will accept as soon as I can review everything.  Thanks again

Comment: This runs very fast but there is a problem because the result returns the gap intervals instead of returning the continuous intervals.

Comment: To clarify, I need to start a new row as soon as a gap of more than 30 min is encountered in the series.  So each row contains a time series in which there are no large gaps (30min).  As soon as we have a large gap, that should trigger a new row that gives us the interval until the next large gap.

Answer (score 1):

An approach like the one below would seem to fit the bill assuming the performance is okay.  I used the `sys.all_tables` catalog view to simulate a log table like the one in your example.  You can vary the first argument to `datediff` to get different results.

```
WITH [Sequenced_Entries] AS
(
    SELECT
        row_number() OVER(ORDER BY [modify_date] ASC) AS 'sequence',
        [modify_date] AS 'event_date'
    FROM
        sys.all_objects
)
SELECT
    f.[sequence] AS 'from_event_sequence',
    f.[event_date] AS 'from_event_date',
    t.[sequence] AS 'to_event_sequence',
    t.[event_date] AS 'to_event_date'
FROM
    [Sequenced_Entries] AS f
        INNER JOIN
    [Sequenced_Entries] AS t
        ON (f.[sequence] = t.[sequence] - 1)
WHERE
    datediff(second, f.[event_date], t.[event_date]) < 30
ORDER BY
    f.[sequence] ASC
```

Don't forget the statement before this one in the batch must be terminated with a `;` or this statement must start with one.

Comment: Sorry my title should be "IGNORE gaps over 30 min".  I dont want the gaps, i want the intervals of time that do not have large gaps.  check the example i gave

Comment: In that case flip around the `>` to a `<` in the where clause.  This will give the complementary answer.  I have also changed the magnitude to `30` and the unit to `second` which should exactly match your requirements.

Comment: The only part of the query you need change is the common table expression (CTE) - the stuff inside the parenthesis immediately after the `WITH` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

```
;with Boundaries as (
    select
        "timestamp" as Stamp,
        coalesce(
            case when datediff(second, prev_timestamp, "timestamp") >= 1800 
                then 1 else 0 end,
            1
        ) as IsBoundary
    from
        T t cross apply (
            select max(t2."timestamp") as prev_timestamp from T t2
            where t2."timestamp" < t."timestamp"
        ) as n
), Blocks as (
    select Stamp, sum(IsBoundary) over (order by Stamp) as BlockNum
    from Boundaries
)
select min(Stamp) as "from", max(Stamp) as "to"
from Blocks
group by BlockNum
```

Remember that `datediff()` just counts interval boundaries so you need to take some care with the time difference. I'm using 1800 seconds here.

If you had a later edition of SQL Server you could use `lead()/lag()` to look for the gaps. But instead of an inner join the cross apply will hopefully be significantly faster.

I think your title "find gaps over 30 minutes" as well as a comment to "ignore gaps less than 30 minutes" has misled some posters who thought that you were only seeking to find the rows that bounded a gap of 30 minutes. This is the only one that addresses the problem according to your desired output. [(Test here.)](http://rextester.com/PUH72448)

Instead of using analytic `sum() over (order by...)` it's a simple matter of replacing it with a scalar subquery.

```
...
), Blocks as (
    select
      Stamp,
      (select sum(b2.IsBoundary) from Boundaries b2 where b2.Stamp <= b.Stamp) as BlockNum
    from Boundaries b
) ...
```

Comment: Problem - i am getting an error "Incorrect syntax near 'order'."

Comment: Is this error because you did not code for SQL 2008?

Answer (score 0):

```
;with cc as (
  select Dt 
    , (select top 1 Dt from #tmp where Dt > ot.Dt order by Dt) as NextDt
  from #tmp ot
)
select Dt AS [FROM], NextDt AS [TO]
from cc
where DATEDIFF(minute, Dt, NextDt) >= 30
order by Dt
```

**Test**

```
create table #tmp (Dt datetime)

insert into #tmp values 
('2015-07-15 15:01:21'),
('2015-07-15 15:17:44'), 
('2015-07-15 15:17:53'), 
('2015-07-15 15:18:34'), 
('2015-07-15 15:21:41'), 
('2015-07-15 15:58:12'), 
('2015-07-15 15:59:12'), 
('2015-07-15 16:05:12'),
('2015-07-15 17:02:12')
```

**Result**

```
FROM                           TO
2015-07-15 15:21:41.000        2015-07-15 15:58:12.000
2015-07-15 16:05:12.000        2015-07-15 17:02:12.000
```

<sub>*If a post answers your question, please Mark it as answer*</sub>

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, but this ran slower than the cursor.  Any ideas?

Comment: how many records do you have in your table? I don't think any set based query can be slower than cursor.

Comment: 100k rows.  ran in about 3 min.

Comment: Can you provide your table schema? do you have any sequential field like identity field in your table? how long it take using cursor?

Comment: if you have identity and your identity is indexed, it will be much faster. I just added index on field Dt and it took 2 seconds for 100k rows. if your identity is clustered index, it will take ZERO second

Comment: I will look into adding index to this set and let you know.  Thanks so much sir.