# SKIP gaps over 30 min in timestamp column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a time series and I need to generate subsets of time intervals that do not have large gaps (anything great than 30 min is a large gap).  This is SQL 2008 so I can't use the `Lead()`/`Lag()` functions.

Every time there is a gap of at least 30 min, I need a new row with the start and end of the next "large gapless" interval. For example If there are no large gaps, result would be one row with the `min` and `max` of the timestamps. If there is 1 'large' gap, there would be 2 rows - from the start of the series to the gap and from the gap to the end. If there are more gaps, we get rows for each interval between the gaps, etc.

Input: `timestamp`

```
2015-07-15 15:01:21
2015-07-15 15:17:44
2015-07-15 15:17:53
2015-07-15 15:18:34
2015-07-15 15:21:41
2015-07-15 15:58:12
2015-07-15 15:59:12
2015-07-15 16:05:12
2015-07-15 17:02:12
```

Desired output :

```
      from          |        to
--------------------+-------------------
2015-07-15 15:01:21 | 2015-07-15 15:21:41
2015-07-15 15:58:12 | 2015-07-15 16:05:12
2015-07-15 17:02:12 | 2015-07-15 17:02:12
```

Thanks so much - I have been working on this for days with no luck and my cursor solution is too slow.

Comment: dont duplicate your own questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37579492/detect-gaps-over-30-min-in-timestamp-column

Comment: btw you can read [**THIS**](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/11/24/sql-server-solution-to-puzzle-simulate-lead-and-lag-without-using-sql-server-2012-analytic-function/) to learn duplicate lag/lead on 2008

Answer (score 1):

here is an example using row_number as a handy replacement for lead and lag

```
;WITH CTE AS (SELECT *, row_number() OVER(order by LogTime) rown from isproclog)
select logtime from cte WHERE NOT EXISTS 
            (SELECT 0 FROM cte cte2 
                        WHERE 
                            CTE2.LogTime < CTE.LogTime 
                            AND 
                            CTE2.LogTime >= DATEADD("mi",-30, CTE.LogTime)
            )
UNION SELECT MIN(LogTime) FROM CTE 
UNION SELECT MAX(LogTime) FROM CTE ORDER BY LogTime
```

Comment: actually I never used the row_number from the CTE, and the UNION SELECT MIN(LogTime) FROM CTE is extra to requirements, since it has no prior row, but the MAX is needed

Comment: select logtime from isproclog CTE WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT 0 FROM isproclog cte2 
       WHERE 
        CTE2.LogTime < CTE.LogTime 
        AND 
        CTE2.LogTime >= DATEADD("mi",-30, CTE.LogTime)
    )
 UNION SELECT MAX(LogTime) FROM isProcLog ORDER BY LogTime

Comment: Thanks Andy.  I will test it out and let ya know :)

Comment: Very long run time

Comment: @user3431083 I amended my answer from two days ago and I believe it should work for you now.

Comment: For some reason I get a 30+ second run time on a mid sized problem when a cursor runs in less than 2 seconds for the same problem.  I thought cursors sucked?